# What is the best way to keep multiple copies of same file in sync?

Tags: svn

I have a directory `/dirA` in which I maintain a bunch of files. They are version controlled by SVN. Now a subset of these files are copied into multiple other directories (`/dirB`, `/dirC` `/dirD`, etc)

Whenever I make any changes to files in `/dirA`, I have to manually copy the changes in `/dirB`, `/dirC` `/dirD`.

I tried doing a SVN checkout of these file in `/dirB`, `/dirC` `/dirD`. But SVN doesn't let me checkout specific files.

I seek help in resolving this issue

Comment: the 'how' of this is easy... the 'why' is the question you should be asking.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).

You can add the Dir-A's subset files / folders as extern to other directories

Answer (score -1):

`svn:externals` property can help you to implement the desired solution. Check `svn:externals` in [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) and [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html).

BTW you can use [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) to get a file from a repository.